# How to propagate trace context in .Net 6 and OpenTelemetry?

Tags: .net, nservicebus, open-telemetry

I would like to add tracing to my .Net 6 app using Open Telemetry, but I have an issue with the context.

I have an app that sends NServiceBus messages to another service and then receives a response event.
My question is how to connect an activity created during response receiving with an original parent Activity? I have a correlation reference in the NServiceBus message, so I have an ID to populate the context with, but I do not know how.

Comment: Are you using the OpenTelemetry support that's included with NServiceBus 8? - https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/opentelemetry. One of the samples _looks_ like it involves connecting activities but I admit I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: It works if that telemetry enabled in both projects, not just in one

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's working now but you don't want to enable OpenTelemetry in both the sender and the receiver?

Comment: I cannot modify the receiver project

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you need to connect the response from the receiver back to the existing trace somehow by mapping the headers or some other metadata to your active spans?

Comment: Yes, I need this

Comment: I believe it's possible but there are more questions about the scenario. It would be quicker to resolve this by submitting a support case at https://particular.net/support where we can get on a call with you. Once resolved, I can add an answer to this question.